# how to export and import style in npm package?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, webpack, styles

I have a React component and I publish the component in NPM registry that I build with webpack. In my main project I consumed the component npm package JS like that:

```js
import myComp from 'myComp';
```

The problem is that `myComp` also has CSS, that I build into `dist/index.css` with the help of webpack and `ExtractTextPlugin` (which builds all the css into one file).

And I want to consume the style like this:

```js
import 'myComp/index.css';
```

Or

```js
import 'myComp/index';
```

And in `myComp` npm package I want to expose it in a way that will support this import method.

NOTE: I don't want to import it directly from `node_modules`

```js
import '../../../node_modules/myComp/index.css'; // bad
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

So it's easier than I thought, all you need to do is import the CSS like that (as I did in the question):

```
import 'myComp/dist/style.css';
```

And make sure your tools (browserify/webpack etc..) can handle loading css into your javascript file.

So the issue was more related to the building process.

---

Also, if you want to push specific code into npm registry you can use "files" inside `package.json`. This way you'll end up with just the files you need in npm registry.

```
files: [
"dist/*.css"
]
```

You can also use tools like:
https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify - for browserify 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcelify-loader - for webpack

But I didn't like them. It forces a dependency on the consumer of your npm package.

Comment: For webpack, do `npm install --save-dev css-loader`.  Then in your webpack.config.js, add this line to the `use` options:  `css-loader`.  Check out https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader.

Comment: Also, be sure directory is not listed in `.gitignore` file, this prevent saving all files in package